# Merging 2 video files together

Tags: vb.net, video, merge, video-processing

I'm building a vb.net application for a entertainment center in the area.

I have some raspberry pi's recording footage with a webcam mounted on an electric kart.

After recording it's copied to my server. The server uploads it to youtube automatically. So customers can see the video online and share it.

BUT the owner wants to add a short intro in front of the footage before uploading it to youtube.

So i tried this

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:Intro.avi|11_2018-03-26_14u21.avi" -f avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy "CombinedVideo.avi"
```

BUT i have the following problem i can't seem to fix.

The intro is 5 secondsand the other videos are longer (different in length every time). but the ffmpeg takes the full 5 second intro and only 5 seconds of the second video.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: There are many experts who can help you but don't you think you need to try something urself first , then we will be glad to help u progress...Always remember , ur failure is your best teacher :) Fail first with ur attempt and comeback with the result .... We want the best for you

Comment: Lookup "FFmpeg".

Comment: i edited my question and posted what i've already tried.

Comment: your concat command should work. i would go on trying different ffmpeg versions. E.g. go for a release instead of nightly build. Latest is 3.4.2 if i am not wrong.

Comment: okay, i found the problem. It doesn't work with AVI.

When i convert the files to MPG and than use the CONCAT function it works.